# Can use special characters without pressing shift key in windows10?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, autohotkey

how can I use number keys in top of keyboard just for special characters like (@#$)
**without** pressing *shift* *key* to use that.
-for example when pressing num2 key  just show @
I search about that just understand can do that with **AutoHotkey** but I don't find script to do that,
actually is not problem. I just want use numeric key Which are located at the top of keyboard use that just for specials characters.

Comment: Set your input language to French;) It’s the only language that does that by default.

Comment: Usually this can be enabled/disabled via the BIOS/UEFI firmware settings

Comment: use this on youre aoutohotkey file :1::!
2::@
3::#
4::$
#CommentFlag // 5::%
6::^
7::&
8::*
9::(
0::)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An AutoHotkey script that does that is very simple:

```
2::@
```

Repeat this for the other keys on the upper keyboard row.

Note that the numpad numeric keys will still keep their values,
so numpad2 will still give "2" and not "@".

Answer (score 0):

1. Install **Power Toys** ([Visit here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/install))
2. Open it and go to *Keyboard Manager*
3. Choose *Remap a key*
4. Click on *Select* and press the one of the keys and click *OK*
5. Select *Text* at *To send* section
6. Click on the field and type the character (Shift + key) and do this for all of number keys
7. Click on *OK* at the top of screen and save the settings
8. Go to general settings of Power Toys and enable *Run at startup*
   Done!!